# If I control for country effects and results are significant, can I conclude generalizability of results?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation, partial-least-squares, controlling-for-a-variable

I am working on a mediated model where M mediates the relationship between X and Y and I have one control variable. The data I am using is from 3 different countries with different sample sizes (46, 64 and 29, total n=139). 
I created country dummy variables where C1 is 1 for the first country and 0 for the other two, C2 is 1 for the second country and 0 for the first and last and included both in my model.
When I ran my analysis (using PLS-SEM in SmartPLS), I got significant results for the main and mediated effects.

[image]

My question is, can I conclude that my results can be generalized across countries? and does the significant effects of C1 and C2 on Y matter?

Any further analysis I should consider?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the scientific question you're trying to answer? Right now, all that the C1 and C2 dummies are doing is reducing residual variability--your model does NOT, for example, allow for different mediation effects by country.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SheridanGrant. I tested the model first using one sample and the results were good (main effect and moderation are significant). Now I want to test if the same relationships apply to other countries. My point is to generalize my results.

Comment: Then you need interaction terms, between C and M (and possibly more). Could be a complicated analysis.